# Why does sh not find files in my path that do exist?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, sh

When I type this in sh it outputs :

```
$ $PATH
sh: 12: /bin:/usr/bin: not found
```

But, I do have a /usr/bin folder, and it's fuuuuull of stuff.

Same thing with zsh:

```
▶ $PATH
zsh: no such file or directory: /bin:/usr/bin
```

What the hell ? How do I fix this ?

Comment: What command are you trying to run? Are you trying to find a command that is in your path?

Comment: @DavidPostill I thinks he is directly writing `$PATH` and executing it.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish Yes, that is clear. But why is he doing that? What's he really tryng to do?

Comment: I think you are trying to run `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

> PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like
>   operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for
>   executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs) in response to commands
>   issued by a user.

To see the value of `PATH` variable, do it as `echo $PATH`. In your case, `sh` will look for executable in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` directory.

Also, you can use your `sh` commands as `/bin/command` if the executable of `command` is in the `/bin` directory. For example, instead of using `ls` you can use `/bin/ls` since writing `ls` runs the executable `ls` present in `/bin`. If the `ls` is not there in `/bin`, then it will look in `/usr/bin`. If `ls` is still not found in both the directory, then it will complain.

Trying to use `$PATH` or `/bin:/usr/bin:` directly, `sh` thinks that it is supposed to run `bin` executable located in the directory `/bin:/usr/`. This is the reason, it give `directory or file not found` or `not found` error.

For detailed info on [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

Comment: So, when I run this :

▶ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/media/HDD/Code/android-sdk-linux/plateform-tools:/media/HDD/Code/android-sdk-linux/tools

They are no more errors, and none in sh

Comment: @N07070 Thats because, `PATH` is an environmental variable, which you are printing using `$PATH`. Hence, there won't be any error.